# Как правильно сделать подготовленный запрос?

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть таблица из которой мне нужно взять данные и отправить пост запросом, на данный момент это выглядит всё это дело вот так

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

if (!empty($_POST["to"])) {

}

$sql = 'SELECT name, email, key FROM post';
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $row['name'] . "\t";
    $row['email'] . "\t";
    $row['key'] . "\t";
}

$url = 'https://site.ru/';
$data = array('key' => $row['key'] . "\t", 'name' => $row['name'] . "\t", 'to' => $_REQUEST['to'], 'email' => $row['email'] . "\t");

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
```

Помогите составить правильный подготовленный запрос в бд и получения массива.

Почему в таком запросе я получаю ошибку

> Syntax error or access violation:
> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

В строке

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `key`, `name`, `email` FROM post_api 
                      WHERE `key` = :key, `name` = :name, `email` = :email");
```

Comment: `1) $query = $db->query($sql); 2) while($res = $query->fetch_array()) { $res['name']; ... }` Об этом речь ? Или о PDO ?

Comment: Не только как составить подготовленный запрос?

Comment: prepare & execute. Инфы в инете полно же. Например, https://prowebmastering.ru/php-pdo-start.html

Comment: У меня прямой запрос $stm = $db->query("SELECT * from post LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: А как мне правильно сделать чтение не одного значения как указано в примере `"SELECT `name` ` а нескольких? Это делается через запятую или точку с запятой нужно указывать? `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM categories WHERE `name` = :name");
$stmt->execute(['name' => $name]);` в данном примере читается только имя категории а если мне нужно прочитать не только имя а ещё какие то данные?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ..` - выбрать все из таблицы .., `SELECT name, email FROM ..` - Выбрать name и email из таблицы